# scala: proving two functions with structural induction

Tags: scala, induction

I have the following two functions in scala:

```
def sum(ls: List[Int]): Int = ls match
{
  case Nil => 0
  case l::ls => l + sum(ls)
}

def turn(ls: List[Int]) : List[Int] = ls match
{
  case Nil => List()
  case l::ls => append(turn(ls), List(l))
}
```

Function `sum(ls)` is calculating the sum of its elements and `turn(ls)` returns me a list with the elements in reversed order. `sum(List(2, 13, 4))` is 19 and `turn(List(2, 13, 4))` is `List(4, 13, 2)`

How can I show with (structural) induction that

```
sum(cs) == sum(turn(cs))
```

holds?

Comment: Using what tool? Isabelle? Z3? Manually?

Comment: I am trying to do it manually

Comment: Ok, and what exactly are you trying then, and where are you stuck? I'm not quite sure in what syntax to write down a possible answer...

Comment: It can easily be demonstrated mathematically by using induction: you check it for a list of size `1` then you just assume the property true for a list of size `n` and prove it at `n+1` by using addition commutative property. It is not related to Scala though..